# Passing large parameters to an iframe

Tags: html, url, iframe, internet-explorer-6

I have an iframe which to i'd like to pass parameters to.

So I do this (ldots means and so on)

```
my_iframe.src = "myaction.do?param1=value1&param2=value2&..."
```

My current problem is that when the query string passes about 2100 characters, the request is not sent.  Background on this is that one of the values passed can be about ~2000 characters long.

I've looked around, and found out that in IE6 (yes, i'm working on it) [theres a 2083 character limit for any url](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

So, i guess there isn't much to do, but to force a lower limit on my 2000 character field, or not using an iframe. This is legacy code, so the iframe is here to stay.

Is there any workaround on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doing a POST operation would get you around the character limit, but with legacy code, is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

While `GET` requests are limited in their length, `POST` requests are not. Some scripts don't care whether their data comes from a GET or a POST, so you might consider having JavaScript post a form to the iframe on page load. This can't be done without JavaScript, but it would definitely bypass the length limitation.